# Replacing multiple lines single line comment in C (escaped newlines)

Tags: c, escaping, comments

I search and reading a lot latest ISO of C and I founded that it could be mutlipleline singleline comment

```
/\
/0
/\
/\
/\
|| <- this si still comment
```

It's really cool, but how can i match this comments to see if there are some in the file.
I tried [this](http://regex101.com/r/oB6lV4)  but It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Don't use that style of commenting. If you want multi-line comments use `/* ... */`

Comment: i know i tried to match these comments. I don't want to use it .. i wanna replace it with /*   */ comments

Comment: Keep removing lines one by one and compiling ... when compiler complains you did something bad (either removed a line you shouldn't or didn't remove a line you should). When compiler doesn't complain, assume everything is ok

Comment: Read your source code as usual, then concatenate all lines ending with the "continuing" character `\\`. Then process "as usual".

Answer (score 0):

I found final regex to match this

```
\/(?:[\\][\n])?\/(?:[\\][\n])?(?:.(?:[\\][\n])?)+
```

example [here](http://regex101.com/r/lO0dZ1)

Comment: I'm so so tempted to vote this down. Guess I'll take a cold shower instead.